# error: mat.isContinuous() when calling cv.ShowImage

Tags: python, opencv

I just upgraded to Python 2.7.4 (from 2.7.3) and OpenCV 2.4.5 (from 2.4.0) as I needed some of the new functionality they come with.

I previously had a couple of lines of code which were working well that basically combine 2 images into one and displays the resulting image. Code below:

```
    def doCombineImages(image1,image2):
        tempImg1 = cv.CreateImage((int(image1.width/imgScale),int(image1.height/imgScale)),cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U,3)
        tempImg2 = cv.CreateImage((int(image1.width/imgScale),int(image1.height/imgScale)),cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U,3)
        cv.Resize(image1, tempImg1)
        cv.Resize(image2, tempImg2)
        outImg = cv.CreateImage(((tempImg1.width*2)+5,tempImg1.height),cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U,3); cv.Zero(outImg)
        cv.SetImageROI(outImg, (0, 0, tempImg1.width, tempImg1.height))
        cv.Copy(tempImg1, outImg)
        cv.ResetImageROI(outImg)
        cv.SetImageROI(outImg, (tempImg2.width+5, 0, tempImg2.width, tempImg2.height))
        cv.Copy(tempImg2, outImg)
        cv.ResetImageROI(outImg)
        return outImg
   .
   .
   .
   .
    image1 = cv.LoadImageM(imageToLoad1, cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
    image2 = cv.LoadImageM(imageToLoad2, cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)

    combiImages = doCombineImages(image1,image2)

    cv.ShowImage('Combined Images',combiImages)
    cv.WaitKey(0)
    cv.DestroyAllWindows()
```

After upgrading as above I get the error:

> cv.ShowImage('Combined Images',combiImages) error: mat.isContinuous()

Initially I had to install ActivePython to get IDLE to work again as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488256/python-idle-is-not-starting-on-windows-7)

Can't seem to find any correct references to this error. Has anyone encountered such an error?

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: Did you try with new interface "cv2" ? "cv" interface is not recommended now. OpenCV has even removed its samples folder (/samples/python) in their git repo.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The idea behind the upgrade is to switch to cv2 and although it was available in my previous version I wanted to start working on the most recent version. My main concern is that I still need to use some of my old code (written using cv) until I complete the switch over. The fact that old code isn't working creates a massive problem and huge urgency in converting all the old code which isn't ideal at this point in time.

Comment: Some additional information... if I change the cv.ShowImage line to display one of the input images, it doesn't throw the error but still doesn't display the image and just displays the image window with a grey background.  I have also completely uninstalled all of python and libraries including opencv and reinstalled everything from scratch. Still no joy!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by uninstalling Python and all libraries and starting from scratch.

Painful, but seems to have worked, although the 64bit versions didn't actually work at first. Only the 32 bit version of Python, Numpy and OpenCV seem to work correctly on my computer.